# Meteor Hanging on Ubuntu when building

Tags: meteor, build, ubuntu-16.04

I have an application that builds in 5 minutes on the Mac.  When I try to build in Docker or directly in Ubuntu, the machine completely hangs at some point.  It so bad that I can't even ssh into the machine.  It eventually times out.  I am using Meteor 1.4.2.3, Ubuntu 16.04 and Docker 16.04 with Meteor installed.

I thought maybe it was related to tar and 7z, so I upgraded tar and 7z.  Still hangs.   It hangs when I building on web.browser.  There is high I/O waits and a bunch of blocked processes according to vmstat.

This is the command I'm running:

```
meteor build --allow-superuser  --server-only  --directory /tmp/build
```

Is their any way to get more info about what's going wrong?  I also tried to

```
meteor remove ecmascript --allow-superuser
```

b/c one article said this may be an issue.  Hangs.

Comment: Our of curiosity- how much RAM does your Ubuntu machine have?

Comment: it's a t2.medium. there is plenty enough memory.  the i/o wait is from "blocked" process, but there is free memory.

Comment: can you run the build in verbose mode and copy the output?

Comment: I was initially a huge fan of Meteor- then I tried to deploy using it.